# Python Looping Random numbers

Tags: python, loops

What I've got to do is get to print out as 5 4 3 2 1
then 4 3 2 1 under that then 3 2 1 and so on, right now all I have is the first line so i'll get 5 4 3 2 1 or 6 5 4 3 2 1 but I can't seem to get it right  when trying to get it to continue until it reaches 1

```
from random import choice
    i=choice([5,6,7,8,9,10])
    while i:
        print(i, end=" ")
        i -= 1
        if(i <1):
            break
```

Comment: Sounds like you need two loops, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compact approach:

```
import random as rnd

length = rnd.choice([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
lst = [str(x) for x in range(length, 0, -1)]
while lst:
    print(" ".join(lst))
    lst.pop(0)
```

Replace `range` with `xrange` if you are using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops, one to do the initial countdown (5, 4, 3, 2, 1), the other to loop through each of the lists you need to produce. For example:

```
from random import choice
i=choice([5,6,7,8,9,10])
for j in [*range(i,0,-1)]:
    for k in [*range(j,0,-1)]:
        print(k, end=" ")
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from random import choice
x = choice([5,6,7,8,9,10])
while x > 0:
    y = x
    while y > 0:
        print y,
        y = y-1
    print "\n"
    x = x-1
```

Comment: Hello, this is the type of code Im looking for but when I  try to run it has an error with the , by the y and the "\n", I've been trying to edit it so it runs but can't seem to get it 100%